# CodeIgniter separated database

Tags: database, codeigniter

My problem is I'm developing a site with CodeIgniter, and the actual site and the admin are separated in different folders and using their own controllers, views, and model.

I would like to use only one `database.php` for both, and I can't really figure out how to point the admin database connection parameter to the site's `database.php`

Could someone give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: If both the sites are at same server - one of the quickest ways to achieve is setup all the values in database.php and in another just remove all the content and add this line - include(/full/path/application/config/database.php) ; I haven't tried that but guess that should work

Comment: There is one thing what i asked for my self why didnt i think of this? thanks so much for your help

Comment: if that worked - shall I create that as an answer to accept?

Comment: so sorry for being slow, yes please, would be happy to give you a pipe  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justing adding my comment above as an answer here so that it helps other to know what worked to solve the problem -

If both the sites are at the same server - one of the quickest ways to achieve this is to setup all the values in database.php and in another just remove all the content and add this line -

```
include(/full/path/application/config/database.php) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two CI structures you can use folders in controllers and views. For example:

```
application
  controllers
    admin
      login.php
```

This will produce a url like: `mysite.com/admin/login/`

Just make sure to not create a Admin class in the root of controllers.

With this you will have just one database configuration for both admin controllers and normal controllers.